# d3.js bubble chart, mousover and mouseout events only working first time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

New to d3. I am having a little trouble with my mouseover and mouseout event handlers.

I wanted split the circles further apart when a circle is selected using the forceCollide function. This works one time and then the circles will either maintain the mouseout or mouseover forceCollide value and not return to their original state.

Any direction on what I am doing wrong is appreciated.

While I am at it, I also cannot get mouseover functions to work if I write them in ES6 syntax, any help with that would be great too, but this may be for another question.

I pasted my code below.

```
d3.csv('../csv/homeless_population.csv')
  .row((data) => {
    return {
      State: data.State,
      PercentHomeless: Number(data.Homeless) / Number(data.Population)
    };
  })
  .get((error, data) => {

    let width = 650;
    let height = 600;

    let maxRadius = d3.max(data, (data) => { return data.PercentHomeless; })
    let minRadius = d3.min(data, (data) => { return data.PercentHomeless; })

    let svg = d3.selectAll('section')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('height', height)
                .attr('width', width)
                .append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')

    let colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemePaired);

    let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                      .force('x', d3.forceX(width/2).strength(0.5))
                      .force('y', d3.forceY(height/2).strength(0.5))
                      .force('collide', d3.forceCollide((data) => { return r(data.PercentHomeless) + 3; }))

    let r = d3.scaleSqrt()
              .domain([minRadius, maxRadius])
              .range([15,75])


    let circles = svg.selectAll('circles')
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append('circle')
                  .attr('stroke', 'black')
                  .attr('fill', (data) => { return colors(data.State); })
                  .attr('r', (data) => { return r(data.PercentHomeless); })
                  .on('mouseover', mouseOn)
                  .on('mouseout', mouseOff)

   function mouseOn(data) {
     circles
      .attr('opacity', 0.5)
     d3.select(this)
      .attr('r', r(data.PercentHomeless) * 1.5)
      .style('opacity', 1)

     simulation
      .force('collide', d3.forceCollide((data) => { return r(data.PercentHomeless * 1.5) + 3; }))
   }

   function mouseOff(data) {
     d3.select(this)
      .attr('r', r(data.PercentHomeless))

     circles
      .attr('opacity', 1)

     simulation
      .force('collide', d3.forceCollide((data) => { return r(data.PercentHomeless) + 3; }))
   }

   let texts = svg.selectAll(null)
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append('text')
                .text((data) => { return data.State; } )
                .attr('color', 'black')
                .attr('font-size', 10)


    let ticked = () => {
      circles
        .attr('cx', (data) => { return data.x; })
        .attr('cy', (data) => { return data.y; })
      texts
        .attr('x', (data) => { return data.x; })
        .attr('y', (data) => { return data.y;  })
    };



    simulation.nodes(data)
      .on('tick', ticked)


  });
```

Comment: I fixed the opacity issue buy changing the .attr to .style, but still trying to figure out the forceCollide issue.

Comment: Since you already fixed the opacity, I removed it from your question. Regarding the arrow function: do you see `this` in the event handlers? That's the reason the arrow function won't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the mouse events work every time. The simulation, on the other hand, has cooled down after the first mouse event, and that's why you don't see any modification in the circles' positions.

Therefore, you have to reheat the simulation in your `mouseOn` and `mouseOff` functions. For instance:

```
simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
```

Here is a demo using a simplified code (since I don't have access to your data). Hover over the circles:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var colour = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var data = d3.range(30).map(d => ({
  r: 6
}));

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(150).strength(0.05))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(75).strength(0.05))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.r + 1;
  }));

var circles = svg.selectAll(".circles")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", d => d.r)
  .attr("fill", (d, i) => colour(i));

circles.on('mouseover', mouseOn)
  .on('mouseout', mouseOff)

simulation.nodes(data)
  .on("tick", d => {
    circles.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
  });

function mouseOn() {
  circles.attr('opacity', 0.5)
  d3.select(this)
    .attr('r', d => d.r * 1.5);

  simulation.force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.r * 1.5 + 1;
  }));

  simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
}

function mouseOff() {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr('r', d => d.r);

  circles.attr('opacity', 1);

  simulation.force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.r + 1;
  }));

  simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();


}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

PS: You don't need to pass `data` to `mouseOn` and `mouseOff` functions.